# How to access in such structure a List<Class> value of a C# Dictionary in a list position, which is a class?

Tags: c#, class, dictionary, unity-game-engine, state-machine

I'm still a new coder, learning how I can. Must confess I tried many approaches, but still not moving forward. This code could be a bit complicated, so tried to show you how it's constructed. 
I want to access the dictionary I made for a state in my State Machine state, which is an instance of a class.
I designed it so I have a state in class (player can switch states), and every state holds state name, description, bool whether there are enemies, dictionary of enemies (number and a list of races), and bool whether there are non-player characters.

Added some more code so you can have an idea of how it all runs / is structured.

Machine was working great before adding monsters, now after I press play I get the error: "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
StateController.GetTransitionsAndActions () (at Assets/_Scripts/GameRPG/StateMachines/StateController.cs:169)
StateController.Start () (at Assets/_Scripts/GameRPG/StateMachines/StateController.cs:131)"
...whis is pointing to that line in State Controller: Monobehaviour script:

```
Debug.Log ("monster.name: " + monster.name);
```

Keep in mind I only show you parts of my scripts, but should be enough to make it debug output in Unity console.

```
public class FunMachine : IStateMachine
{

    List<FunMachineState> mStates;
    FunMachineState mCurrent;
    FunMachineState mExit;
    List <Monster> monsterList = new List<Monster> ();

    public FunMachine()
    {       
        List <Monster> monsterList = new List<Monster> ();
        MonsterManualVol1 monsterManualVol1 = new MonsterManualVol1 (monsterList);

        FunMachineState entryHall = new FunMachineState("Grand Entrance", "You are standing in a grand enterance of a castle.\nThere are tables and chairs, but nothing you can interact with.", "Enter the Grand Entrance", true, new Dictionary<int, Monster> (){{7, monsterList.Find(x => x.name.Contains("orc"))}}, false);
        // (...) many other similar states here
    }

    // Hook up doors.
    entryHall.Neighbors.Add(staircase);
    entryHall.Neighbors.Add(mExit);
    // Add them to the collection
    mStates = new List<FunMachineState>();
    mStates.Add(entryHall);
    // Finally set my starting point
    mCurrent = entryHall;

    #region IStateMachine Overrides
    public override IState CurrentState
    {
        get { return mCurrent; }
    }

    public override List<FunMachineState> PossibleTransitions()
    {
        List<FunMachineState> transitionResult = mCurrent.Neighbors;
        return transitionResult = mCurrent.Neighbors;
    }

    public override Dictionary<int, Monster> GetStateMonsters ()
{
    Dictionary<int, Monster> result = new Dictionary<int, Monster> ();
    List <Monster> monsterList = new List<Monster> ();
    MonsterManualVol1 monsterManualVol1 = new MonsterManualVol1 (monsterList);

    result = mCurrent.Monsters;
    return result;
    }

    // (...) more code
}
```

FunMachineState:

```
public class FunMachineState : IState
{
    string mName;
    string mDescription;
    string mPlayerChoiceButtonText;
    bool mEnemies;
    bool mNpcs;
    Dictionary<int, Monster> mEnemyDictionary;

    List<FunMachineState> mNeighbors = new List<FunMachineState>();
    public List<FunMachineState> Neighbors { get { return mNeighbors; } }

    public Dictionary <int, Monster> Monsters { get { return mEnemyDictionary; } }

    public FunMachineState(string mName, string mDescription, string mPlayerChoiceButtonText, bool mEnemies, Dictionary<int, Monster> mEnemyDictionary, bool mNpcs)
    {
        this.mName = mName;
        this.mDescription = mDescription;
        this.mPlayerChoiceButtonText = mPlayerChoiceButtonText;
        this.mEnemies = mEnemies;
        this.mEnemyDictionary = mEnemyDictionary;
        this.mNpcs = mNpcs;
    }

    #region IState Overrides
    public override string GetName()
    {
        Debug.Log ("Here mName runs!");
        return mName;   
    }

   public override string GetStateDescriptionText()
   {
        return mDescription;
   }

    public override Dictionary<int, Monster> GetStateMonsters()
    {
        return Monsters;
    }
    // (...) more code
}
```

IStateMachine:

```
public abstract class IStateMachine
{
    // List of all possible transitions we can make from this current state.
    public abstract List<FunMachineState> PossibleTransitions();
    // Get those monsters.
    public abstract Dictionary<int, Monster> GetStateMonsters ();
    // (...) more code
}
```

IState:

```
public abstract class IState
{
    public abstract Dictionary<int, Monster> GetStateMonsters ();
    // Do something
    public abstract void Run();
    // (...) more code
}
```

Now run it:

```
public class StateController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public StateController stateController;
    IStateMachine machine = GetMachine();

    private static IStateMachine GetMachine()
    {
        IStateMachine machine = null;
        machine = new FunMachine();
        return machine;
    }

    void Start()
    {

        if (!machine.IsComplete())
        {
            Debug.Log("Currently in " + machine.CurrentState);
            machine.CurrentState.Run();
            Text_main_game_content.text = machine.CurrentState.GetStateDescriptionText();
        GetTransitionsAndActions ();
        }

        public void GetTransitionsAndActions(){
        Dictionary<int, Monster> monsterlisting = machine.CurrentState.GetStateMonsters();

            if (monsterlisting.Values.Count > 0)
            foreach (var monster in monsterlisting.Values) {
            Debug.Log ("monster.name: " + monster.name);
            }
        }
    }
    // (...) more code
}
```

And my monster collection:

```
public class Monster
{
    public string name, description;
    public bool hostile;
    public int hitPoints;
    public int damage;
    public int loot;
    public string coin_type;

    public Monster (string c_name, string c_description, bool c_hostile, int c_hitPoints, int c_damage, int c_loot, string c_coin_type)
    {
        name = c_name;
        description = c_description;
        hostile = c_hostile;
        loot = c_loot;
        hitPoints = c_hitPoints;
        coin_type = c_coin_type;
        damage = c_damage;          
    }
}

public class MonsterManualVol1 
{

    public MonsterManualVol1 (List <Monster> c_monsterList) 
    {
        List <Monster> monsterList = new List<Monster> ();
        monsterList = c_monsterList;
        monsterList.Add (goblin);
        monsterList.Add (orc);
    }
    Monster goblin = new Monster("Goblin", "Cute goblin", true, 7, 5, 28, "sz");
    Monster orc = new Monster("Orc", "Pretty orc", true, 6, 6, 20, "sz");
}
```

I really don't know what's going on. Tried to convert that dictionary to list, didn't work too.

Oh, and this debugs properly at the start of state machine. Addition to public class FunMachine: IStateMachine:

```
public class FunMachine : IStateMachine
{       

    public override List<Monster> MonsterListDebug () {
        monsterList = new List<Monster> ();
        MonsterManualVol1 monsterManualVol1 = new MonsterManualVol1 (monsterList);
        Debug.Log ("monsterList.Count: " + monsterList.Count);

        for (int i = 0; i < monsterList.Count; i++)
        {
            Debug.Log ("Monster name: " + monsterList [i].name +
                " Monster description: " + monsterList [i].description +
                " Monster hostility: " + monsterList [i].hostile +
                " Monster hit points: " + monsterList [i].hitPoints + 
                " Monster hit damage: " + monsterList [i].damage + 
                " Monster hit loot: " + monsterList [i].loot + " " + monsterList [i].coin_type);
        }
        return monsterList;
    }

   public FunMachine()
   {
   // (...)
   //MonsterListDebug (monsterList);    
    MonsterListDebug ();    
   // (...)
   }
// (...)
}
```

I just can't get it to debug from actual CurrentState in StateController, which runs the game properly. Debug only works from FunMachine class, like shown above. Foreach loop in StateController drops null reference, that's the only problem. Monodevelop shows no errors.

Comment: The process to debug NREs is first to find which varaible is `null`, then trace back to find out _why_ it's null.  If you can identify _what_ is null we might be able to help find out _why_, but with a mountain of code it's hard to tell.

Comment: The down voter may be looking for a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or thinks that you should try [debugging this yourself](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  Also, you reference a property Monsters but I couldn't find an implementation of that property.

Comment: Ok, it all boils down to running: Dictionary<int, Monster> monsterlisting = machine.CurrentState.GetStateMonsters(); in public class StateController : MonoBehaviour.
When you look at that function, you can go back to easily find out what's going on. Maybe I'll update the question with that comment.

Comment: You are right, adding Monsters property, my fault. But not sure I can make it shorter, guess you'd ask for more info. // property added!

Comment: @DStanley that part is clear, the null variable is .name of monster.name  in `if (monsterlisting.Values.Count > 0)
            foreach (var monster in monsterlisting.Values) {
            Debug.Log ("monster.name: " + monster.name);
            }` in StateController : Monobehaviour. That's where the problem happens - I properly get monsterlisting.Values.Count. Just can't get any property from foreach loop via monster.name. All properties of monster throw reference not set, even while Monodevelop gets them properly. Unity fails.

Comment: In the `FunMachine` constructor you are  passing a new `Dictionary` with a key of 7 and a value that appears to be empty (where you have the `.Find` on the empty list of monsters. This will result in your dictionary having 1 entry with {7, null} so in your `foreach` you are trying to access that null value

Comment: Ok guys... I have that problem solved. And it's more than silly. I should .Find "Goblin", but I searched for "goblin"... that's all. Honestly, sheesh. Contacting moderation to delete that topic entirely, all was fine with the code - just wrong case of a letter! ...

Comment: *... the null variable is .name of monster.name*.  No, it is not.  If the exception is happening on `Debug.Log ("monster.name: " + monster.name);` then it is `monster` that is null. You can use null reference variables all day, as long as you don't call a method or property on it.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**

> Ok guys... I have that problem solved. ...  I looked for "orc", while it's just "Orc"... That's all.

Uh, not quite. You found one way to induce the bug. You have not solved the problem.

The solution is not:

- Just type a correctly cased string
- Implement a case insensitive name search

I should be able to search for "Yabadabadoo" and not get a `NullReferenceException`.

KMussa's answer gets to it. That `Dictionary<int, Monster>` should handle null values. The fix is in 2 parts:

- Part 1

  - Don't instantiate both class-level and local variables.
  - I think what you meant to do in the method is: `monsterlist.Clear()`
- Part 2

  - Don't allow null dictionary values
  - or, [implement the null object pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/null_object) for the `Monster` class
  - or, guard for null when iterating the dictionary
  - or, [implement an iterator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/65zzykke(v=vs.100).aspx) for the "monster collection" that will not pass null values to the iterating client code.

The best way to do part 2 is to write a custom "MonsterCollection" or "MonsterDictionary" class. Then the easiest fix would be an `Add()` method that rejects null stuff.

If both parts are not done, the problem is not fixed.

**end Edit**

Easier, cleaner debugging.

Move this ...

```
"Monster name: " + monsterList [i].name +
            " Monster description: " + monsterList [i].description +
            " Monster hostility: " + monsterList [i].hostile +
            " Monster hit points: " + monsterList [i].hitDice + 
            " Monster hit damage: " + monsterList [i].damage + 
            " Monster hit loot: " + monsterList [i].loot + " " + monsterList
```

... to `Monster` and override `ToString`. then:

```
for (int i = 0; i < monsterList.Count; i++)
    {
        Debug.Log (monsterList[i].ToString());
    }
    return monsterList;
```

... and even better, also override `ToString` in `MonsterManualVol1` then the `for` loop goes away and you're left with:

```
Debug.Log(monsterList.ToString());
```

Write a `ToString` for `StateController`. Of course this will also include calling `ToString` for it's properties.

In fact, write `ToString` for all your classes and really clean up logging code.

---

Don't need to both initialize and set a property in the constructor:

```
public class FunMachine : IStateMachine
{
  List <Monster> monsterList = new List<Monster> ();

  public FunMachine()
  {       
    List <Monster> monsterList = new List<Monster> ();        
  }
```

---

Test string parameters for null:

```
public Monster (string c_name, ...)
{
    name = c_name; // could be null
    // so:
    name = c_name ?? string.Empty;
```

---

In Visual Studio, do you have Debug | Exceptions... set?

Comment: I'm using Monodevelop, on Mac now, I'm afraid. Nothing set different from default, didn't do anything with Exceptions yet.
I can do that with code, thanks, but that debug works fine. I get both monsters with all their info showing properly while debugging from FunMachine class. Problem is only with getting debug working from StateController, which starts my State Machine and get CurrentState. CurrentState is needed, because that state will be showed to the player. I need to get dictionary of mCurrent (which is a current state thanks to function: public override IState CurrentState.

Comment: well, a general guideline for myself is to clean up the code a bit.  Don't let yourself ignore good coding practices when getting desperate to find a bug. That's what I perceive happening here (been there!). It's hard to find the pony when it's buried under an unnecessarily large and messy pile of crap.

Comment: Right, so fixing that now. No errors in Monodevelop though, only after I start state machine, which runs the function: `public void GetTransitionsAndActions(){
        Dictionary<int, Monster> monsterlisting = machine.CurrentState.GetStateMonsters();

            if (monsterlisting.Values.Count > 0)
            foreach (var monster in monsterlisting.Values) {
            Debug.Log ("monster.name: " + monster.name);
            }
        }`

Comment: That's exactly where the problem occurs, no need to seek elswhere - all is working fine untill that code runs.

Comment: Ok, made override in this way and works great:   `return string.Format ("Monster name: {0} | Monster description: {1} | Monster hostility: {2} | Monster hit dice: {3} | Monster hit points: {4} | Monster hit damage: {5} |  Monster hit loot: {6}", 
   name, description, hostile, hitDice, hitPoints, damage, loot);` Now I've also isolated the case... Will be reposting soon in a really short version!

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to follow the exact flow, but my guess is that the problem lies in this part:

```
List <Monster> monsterList = new List<Monster> ();

public FunMachine()
{       
    List <Monster> monsterList = new List<Monster> ();

    FunMachineState entryHall = new FunMachineState("...", "...", "...", true, 
       new Dictionary<int, Monster> (){{7, monsterList.Find(x => x.name.Contains("orc"))}}, false);
//...
}
```

Specifically, you are declaring a *class variable* called `monsterList` and another *local variable* with the same name inside your constructor - at that stage both lists will be empty, so when you call `monsterList.Find(x => x.name.Contains("orc"))` you get back `NULL`; your dictionary then has an item with key = 7 and value = null

You later try to loop through the dictionary entries and print the monster name and get a `NullReferenceException`

Comment: Turns out it was even more simple... I looked for "orc", while it's just "Orc"... That's all. Sheesh. Asked moderator to remove that topic. All code runs perfectly now, cleaned it up also.

Comment: upvote. You took the time to trace through to the code. My original answer mentions the local variable instantiation but not its effect.